# JavaScript/jQuery client for REST web services

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, restful-authentication

I am a beginner to REST web services and am building a client JavaScript library for my application which needs to do some AJAX calls to the server. Both are hosted on the same domain as to not cause any cross-domain problems in the case of Mozilla/Chrome. The server-side implementation needs to know the username and password (both embedded) of the GET request coming in, something like:

```
request.open(reqtype,url,async,username,pwd)
```

How can i do this in jQuery?

```
jquery.get()

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Is there any embedded option of sending username and password for the REST service in the request using `$.get()`?

Answer (score 1):

Read the jQuery documentation for their AJAX API first, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get. For username and password do not do a GET as it will send them as querystring values. Do a POST.

Answer (score 0):

add them the the header property using the Authorization field.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.8